# 6 x 14 plate with 2x12 plate molded on top and metal contacts on the bottom identification

Tags: part-identification, trains, battery

Needing help identifying this part as I was offered a small bag of vintage train parts and this come with some very unknown parts to me.

I just recently got out of a 33 year old *Dark Age* and have zero experience regarding vintage trains, so hoping somebody could jump in and offer me a hand.

[image: Top and bottom of the unknown part]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

*[Part# BB0054 - Electric, Train 4.5V Battery Car Roof.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bb0054&name=Electric,%20Train%204.5V%20Battery%20Car%20Roof&category=%5BElectric,%20Train%5D#T=S&C=9&O=%7B%22color%22:%229%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)*

(But Light Gray in color.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is it. Now, I wish I started on LEGO earlier, everything now costs a small fortune :)